# Checking html closing tags using java

Tags: java

I want to check html file for closing tags in Java. If closing tags are not there then put closing tag. 
Can anyone Please tell me how to achieve that.

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Comment: This sound impossible to me. There would be no way to know if `<b>some text` should become `<b>some text</b>` or `<b>some</b> text`, for example...

Comment: I haven't started yet. Please tell me how should I proceed.

Comment: I would not say that this is impossible, when you have `<b> some text` its quit clear that the result is `<b> some text </b>`. But writing an own parser is very complex. I also would suggest to have a look at TagSoup like Sajal wrote in his answer

Answer (score 2):

I used [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) for that.

> A SAX-compliant parser written in Java that, instead of parsing
>   well-formed or valid XML, parses HTML...
>
> TagSoup is free and Open Source software.

Comment: Thanks Sajal. I'll check and get back to u.